# Angular Material Table error: "...MatCellDef does not define an implicit value"

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular-material

In all my Angular Material tables through out my app I get an error for each td tag and the bottom tr tags

> The template context of 'MatCellDef' does not define an implicit value.
>   If the context type is a base type, consider refining it to a more specific type.

Table:

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="businessLocations">    
  <ng-container matColumnDef="business_city">
   <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> City </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let location">{{location.business_city}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Some of the TS:

```
 this.businessLocations = response.businessLocations;
 this.businessLocations =  new MatTableDataSource(this.businessLocations);
```

I can provide more code if needed.
I'm using Visual Studio Code with Angular Essentials plugin.
Cant seem to find any answer on this

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it worked.

`import { TemplateModule } from '@template/template.module';`

`imports: [ /* Other imported modules */ TemplateModule ], exports: [ /* Other exported modules */ TemplateModule  ]`

Make sure to stop the lit server or close Visual Studio Code and open it again.